# Prácticas correctas a la hora de desarrollar test automatizados

Tags: java, selenium, test-ng

soy un desarrollador muy Junior, que acaba de terminar sus estudios.

Me encuentro trabajando en un proyecto de automatización de pruebas con Selenum y TestNG, con Java. Siguiendo un patrón de diseño **POM**.

Dentro de mi class "Base", tengo definido un método que busca un WebElemnet y los retorna

```
    public static WebElement findElement(FluentWait<WebDriver> fwait, By locator, String driverKey) {
        try {
            fwait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
            List<WebElement> elements = Utilities.getInstance(driverKey).getDriver(driverKey).findElements(locator);

            if (elements.size() == 1) {
                System.out.println("Se ha encontrado un elemento. Con el localizador: " + locator);
                return elements.get(0);
            } else if (elements.size() > 1) {
                System.out
                        .println("Se han encontrado más de un elemento. La búsqueda no es precisa para el localizador: "
                                + locator);
                return null;
            } else {
                assert false : "No se encontró el elemento con el localizador: " + locator;
                System.out.println("No se han encontrado elementos con el localizador: " + locator);
                return null;
            }
        } catch (AssertionError e) {
            assert false : "No se encontró el elemento con el localizador: " + locator;
            System.out.println("Error al esperar el elemento: " + locator);
            return null;
            
        }
```

Y una de mis tantas dudas es:

¿Me tendría que crear una excepción para este nuevo método?
al igual que assert, lo tendría que lanzar en el método "findElement" o cuando sea llamado en un test, si dicho método retorna null, lanzar el assert fasle.

Muchas gracias!!! P.D.:"Perdona si la nomenclatura de algunos términos no es correcta, llevo poco tiempo en este ámbito. Gracias por tu comprensión."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estimado le recomiendo revisar el modelo page factory https://www.tutorialselenium.com/2019/02/05/page-object-model-selenium-webdriver/ combinado con el patron de diseño POM, se utilizan sentencias webelement mucho mas sencillas de trabajar los elementos. Luego a modo recomendación tener una clase generica para ir dejando ciertos metodos y funciones reutilizables como validarElementoExistente, tiempos de espera, etc.

Y respondiendo la pregunta: Si tienes que crear un assert.fail cuando no encuentra el elemento o la condición caiga en el trycatch

Comment: Está respuesta podría caber en un comentario. Sugiero que te explayes un poco más y le des más un aspecto de publicación.